# Find difference between two array of psobject?

Tags: powershell

The following code creates two sample array of psobject. How to get the difference of `$a` and `$b` by property `A` and `X` where `A*2 <> X` (just an example, it can be any complex predict)?

```
$a = 1..5 | % { New-Object -TypeName psobject -Property (@{A = $_; B= "..." }) }
$b = 2..6 | % { New-Object -TypeName psobject -Property (@{X = $_*2; Y= "..." }) }
```

The list of item(s) in `$a` but not in `$b`: 1

The list of item(s) in `$b` but not in `$a`: 12

Basically, if the code is written in a F#/C# language. It will require something like `not (list.Exists(x => predict(x)))`, which needs a lambda.

Answer (score 1):

This maybe?

The list of item(s) in `$a` but not in `$b`:

```psh
Compare-Object $a $b -Property a,b | ? { $_.SideIndicator -eq "<=" } |
  select -Expand a
```

The list of item(s) in `$b` but not in `$a`:

```psh
Compare-Object $a $b -Property a,b | ? { $_.SideIndicator -eq "=>" } |
  select -Expand a
```

Comment: Actually the two ps objects may have very different field names etc. I just updated the question.

Comment: @dc7a9163d9 Can you rename the properties of one object to match the other object? Otherwise the only option I see is to write a custom comparison function where you define how the objects should be compared. How else do you expect to compare objects that don't have anything in common at all?

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers The actually column name will come from another script and cannot be renamed. And the comparison is not simple text match. It needs some calculation. I've revised the question.

Answer (score 0):

Skipping the `compare-object` cmdlet you could iterate through `$a` and check if a calculated property of each object is in the array of values for whatever property for `$b`. That sounds confusing, but I think an example should help...

```
$a|?{($_.a*2) -notin $b.x}
```

Or reversed:

```
$B|?{($_.x/2) -notin $A.a}
```

I suppose you could make a function for it, something like:

```
Function CalculatedCompare{
Param(
    [Object[]]$InputObject,
    [String]$InputProperty,
    [Object[]]$DifferenceObject,
    [String]$DifferenceProperty,
    [String]$Conversion
)
    $InputObject | Where{$([ScriptBlock]::Create("$($_.$InputProperty)$conversion").Invoke()) -notin $differenceobject.$differenceproperty}
}
```

I just kind of made that up on the fly, but I don't see any reason that it wouldn't work off the top of my head.

Ok, I just pasted it into the ISE and it works. Using your sample data I did:

```
CalculatedCompare $a 'a' $b 'x' '*2'
```

And the function spit back the one record where `$A.A` is '1'.